# Fileupload in gridview edittemplate not working in update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I have the fileupload control inside gridview edittemplate:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Template File" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTemplateFileName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TemplateFileName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <EditItemTemplate>

                                                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuTemplate" runat="server" />
                                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfTemplateFile" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="fuTemplate"
                                                                            runat="server" ErrorMessage="Select the Template File!" ValidationGroup="GRD"
                                                                            Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

GridView is inside the update panel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMain" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
...............
..............
</ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When through rowcommand I check fileuploader.Hasfile , and it always shows false although it has the file.

I tried having postbacktrigger for the grid as well as the fileuploader.

But it was not of use.

How can I deal with this problem?

Please guide me.

Have also tried adding :

```
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

On page load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File Upload will not work with a partial post back.
So just add this line at your page load

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(this.YourGridviewId);
```

Or use `PostBackTrigger`.

```
<Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="YourGridviewId" />
</Triggers>
```

Or You need special AsyncFileUpload control as defined in AjaxControl Toolkit.

```
<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload OnClientUploadError="uploadError"
     OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" runat="server"
     ID="AsyncFileUpload1" Width="400px" UploaderStyle="Modern"
     UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF" ThrobberID="myThrobber" />
```

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389522/asp-net-fileupload-in-updatepanel-still-not-working).