# File upload button not showing files when uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal popup and in the modal-body I have two asp.net controls `FileUpload` control and `LinkButton` and the markup is

```
<div class="modal-body">    
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="optinFileUpload"></asp:FileUpload>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnImport" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" OnClick="btnImport_Click" Text="Import"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

Then I'm uploading the button and click the Import button and code behind is

```
protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool val = optinFileUpload.HasFile;
}
```

And the val is always showing `false` even if it contains the file.

Can one tell me why it is always showing false

Comment: are you using update panel?

Comment: if your file upload button will be inside update panel then it will show always false.

Comment: if its inside updatepanel it will always show false. use asyncfileupload control in ajaxtoolkit for use with update panel

Comment: You were right it is in update panel and when I have removed it is showing the right results

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET FileUpload in UpdatePanel - still not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389522/asp-net-fileupload-in-updatepanel-still-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
     {
          string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
          postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + fileName);
     }
```

http://www.itorian.com/2014/01/single-file-upload-to-multiple-file.html