# Fileupload inside UpdatePanel becomes null

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, null, user-controls, updatepanel

Dears,

Updatepanel is in Aspx page.

I have a fileupload in .ascx control. Ascx user control is added when its called and every thing else (rest of page controls i.e. listview) works fine on ascx control.

Only fileupload is set to null when Add Button click is fired. I have tried accepted code (**another thread in stackoverflow [Persist FileUpload Control Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651039/persist-fileupload-control-value)**) in Page_Load and even Page_Init but still it becomes null.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: `FileUpload` and 'UpdatePanel` do not work together. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389522/asp-net-fileupload-in-updatepanel-still-not-working.

Comment: Thanks alot for helping. What if the updatepanel is on Masterpage, and fileupload is on a usercontrol that is getting added on runtime (dynamically) in an aspx page. Where to put the trigger